# How To Bind Variable Under Summation Sign

Tags: notation, index-notation

I just wanted to sum over all vertices $v'\in V$ of a graph (where $v$ is given) such that $\{v,v'\}\in E$ while also binding the variable $e$ to $\{v,v'\}$ and realized that mathematical notation is a bit restricted in what you can do in such a case.  Here are a few possibilities, where $T$ is some arbitrary term using $v'$ and $e$:

- $\sum_{v'\in V:(e:=\{v,v'\})\in E}T[v',e]$
- $\sum_{v'\in V, e\in E: e=\{v,v'\}}T[v',e]$
- $\sum_{v'\in V: \exists e\in E.e=\{v,v'\}}T[v',e]$

I think the first one is a bit unconvential, but could be understood from the context.  The second one is technically correct, but a bit misleading because it looks like a double sum when in fact it reduces to a 'single sum'.  The last one is definitely technically false, as the scope of $e$ ends after the sum sign and $e$ is undefined inside $T$.  In Haskell there is the as-pattern for such bindings, which I think would also be handy in math, like $e@\{v,v'\}$, but I have never seen it before.  Is there maybe some good alternative to the notations I described?

Comment: In all of those you have a "v" without having said what v was.  If you want v' such that the pair (v, v') is in E then you will have to specify what v is.  Is it specified outside the formula?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the $v$ is meant to be specified before.  I just want to loop over all $v'$ with $\{v,v'\}\in E$ and simultaneously bind $e$ to that pair.  In many programming languages, the body of the sum would be a block and I could define $e$ in the first line of the block.

Comment: Establish notation that specifies the vertices of an edge. Perhaps $e_1$ or $e(1)$ for the first vertex.

Comment: That works for directed graphs.  I thought about establishing the notation $e(v)$ to denote the *other* vertex than $v$ in $e$, not sure how common that is.  But I feel there could be cases similar to the one I described outside of graph theory, where one just wants to bind a variable within a loop expression.

Comment: Unless you need this a lot, just use words rather than establishing a new notation.